# PHP Array Sort and group

Tags: sorting

Below is an array with count and its button url, need to sort and group duplicate items in new array and sorted:

```html
$array = [[
   [1,'Firsts','https://test.com/button-1', ''],
   [1,'Seconds','https://test.com/button-2', ''],
   [2,'Testing-Button','https://test.com/copy.jpg', ''],
   [19,'LetsStart','https://test.com/', ''],
   [4,'Firsts','https://test.com/button-3', ''],
   [5,'Seconds','https://test.com/button-4', ''],
   [10,'Firsts','https://test.com/button-5', '']
 ]];
```

**Expected Output:**

```html
$output = [[
   [1,'Firsts','https://test.com/button-1', ''],
   [1,'Seconds','https://test.com/button-2', ''],
   [2,'Testing-Button','https://test.com/copy.jpg', ''],
   [19,'LetsStart','https://test.com/', '']
  ],
  [
   [4,'Firsts','https://test.com/button-3', ''],
   [5,'Seconds','https://test.com/button-4', '']
  ],
  [
   [10,'Firsts','https://test.com/button-5', '']
  ]
   ];
```

Comment: Format of each array item contains ['count','title','url','']

Comment: And what have you tried?